# Attach a jQuery listener to all <a> elements and grab their ids?

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I need to get the id of all the `<a>` links so I can make an Ajax post based on what they are

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('a').click(function(e) {
       var linker = this.attr('id');
       alert(linker);
       // Here I will then make an Ajax call, but I know how to do that :)
   });
});
```

Comment: Do you need to get the `id`s of *all* the `a`s when you click on just one of them and then put them into an array? @Pointy: It's poorly worded, but it's definitely a question. And I'd recommend telling the author why instead of just saying it.

Comment: @Pointy Purmou is right - If you see a terrible question that you think can be improved to make it useful, improve it. You get karma on StackOverflow for curating content too, remember.

Answer (score 5):

`this` isn't a jQuery object, so you can't call `attr` on it; you need `$(this)` for that method to be available.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('a').click(function(e) {
       var linker = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(linker);
       // Here I will then make an Ajax call, but I know how to do that :)
   });
});
```

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
var linker = this.id;
```

But that's not enough jQuery `;)`

Comment: thanks it works perfect im new to jquery im a php guy thanks man again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to resist the urge to correct all the spelling and grammar here and just get to the point:

Your script should look like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
   };
});
```

You don't need to look at the "attr" property for native properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').click(function(e) {
       var linker = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(linker);
       // Here I will then make an Ajax call, but I know how to do that :)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better than using jQuery to get the ID is to use straight javascript with `this.id`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('a').click(function(e) {
       var linker = this.id;
       alert(linker);
       // Here I will then make an Ajax call, but I know how to do that :)
   });
});
```

jQuery should be used ONLY when it's better than straight javascript.  In this case, the jQuery way $(this).attr("id") is two unnecessary function calls when `this.id` gets you exactly what you wanted.